# access Component state value in renderDOM

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

This is my app.jsx and i want to access `isAdmin` state of `Login Component` into app.js...`isAdmin` identifies whether user is admin or not and based upon the value..i want to manipulate the routes....How i can achieve this ??

Please help i am new to react...

```
 import Login from './components/Forum/login';
 console.log("login",Login.this.state.isAdmin);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Base}>
         <IndexRoute component={isAdmin == true ? DashboardV1 : ChartFlot } />
            <Route path="dashboard" component={DashboardV1}/>
            <Route path="dashboardv2" component={DashboardV2}/>
            <Route path="dashboardv3" component={DashboardV3}/>
            <Route path="form-cropper" component={FormCropper}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use React's refs to components.

in app.jsx

```
<Login ref="myLogin" />
```

...
then call that component using ref.

```
console.log(this.refs.myLogin.isAdmin);
```

check out Facebook's documentation about React's Refs to Components [here.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Comment: but in rectDOM.render how can i user that ?

Comment: then just export the function isAdmin from Login component and call in in the  React Dom render. Inside the isAdmin function would be this.state.isAdmin.